# How can I make the sound files work again when using the Creation Kit for Special Edition?

Tags: editors, skyrim-modding

When using the CreationKit 64bit for Skyrim Special Edition, the scenes and dialogues break and don't show up properly in game.

What happens and how do I fix it?

Comment: Hello and welcome to a StackExchange site. You'll notice that I have modified all of your questions & answer. SE sites are Question and Answer sites, not "introduction" and "core", i.e. you can't just split up a Reddit post into two parts. We're glad to see you wanting to help fellow users, however we'd like you to do so in a SE manner: Question posts should be used to describe an issue, Answer post should be used to address the issue. Also, please state when you copy/paste content from the internet, it helps avoid plagiarism issues. Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you, I copied articles I wrote earlier on reddit myself.
Thank you also for the modification to make my support posts here fit the custom shape,
I will try to keep that in mind!
Allow me the question, what does SE stand for?

Comment: SE stands for StackExchange, all the sites of the network.

Comment: FWIW, after a couple of days, you're allowed to accept your own Answers. If you think that the Answers provided to the Questions are the right solutions (which I believe you think is the case), you should accept them; this will 1) tell other folks that the answer proved to be useful to solve the issue, and 2) tell the system that the issue is solved (this in turn prevents the community bot to bump the question forever).

Answer (score 1):

*This question&answer is a cross-post of one of my posts on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/skyrimmods/comments/ry4vc2/creation_kit_not_generating_voice_sound_files_3/).*

---

Since the introduction of CreationKit 64bit for Skyrim Special Edition, the in-built tool to generate sound files did no longer work within the response tab of your dialogue. Technically, you cannot directly take records during a CK session, and the result is that scenes and dialogues break and do not show up properly in-game.

This is what you can do:

1. place a folder with a dummy file. Use the Stock\_1.fuz from fuz roh doh download. `Data\Sound\Voice\(yourmodname.esp)\(yourvoicetypename)\ the ID of the voice line` you read in your response-*FuzRohDoh:* [Fuz Ro D-oh - Silent Voice](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/15109)
2. get this dummy file automatically inserted by Fuz Roh Doh, will work for LE, SE and AE if you have the most recent SKSE. You could avoid AE by downgrading your AE to SE again. *Downpatcher:*  [Unofficial Skyrim Special Edition Downgrade Patcher](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/57618) (Note that you can apparently now use FuzRohDoh again for AE since 09.01.2022, I did not test it yet.)
3. record in legendary edition with the tool provided in Creation Kit.

It is suggested however to use 1 or 2 for dummy files and later replace them with high-quality mastered voice records. Usually, voice actors are happy to support you, and some editing can really help to normalize the files and remove unwanted hall effects and other noise. Alternatively, you can use the voice line generator tool, which is surprisingly well working. If you are interested, have a look at the detailed tutorial for using xVASynth here: [Auto-Generate Voice Lines using xVASynth](https://wiki.beyondskyrim.org/wiki/Arcane_University:XVASynth#Step_5_-_Combining_audio_.26_lip_files_to_fuz_file)

References:

- [Reddit: New Creation Kit - cannot create voice files](https://www.reddit.com/r/skyrimmods/comments/5bm9o9/new_creation_kit_cannot_create_voice_files/)
- [Nexus forums: Can't save voice files from CK?](https://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/5034605-cant-save-voice-files-from-ck/page-2#entry103893433)

Disclaimer:

1. I do not take any responsibility for missing files or broken games, I just share the approach in best faith, with the goal of helping you to find the solution yourself, at your own risk.
2. Thank you to everyone working with me on Creation Kit contents, especially Elscrux, Thingy, and Jani. This is mostly a fix for starters, anyone who knows their way around CK is probably aware of this method by logic.